# Disable encoded url showing non encoded url's content

Tags: uri

My drupal website is indexed in Google and I found a link to http://mysite.com/node/345%3Fpage%3D1?page=2 while searching

When I click it it shows content of http://mysite.com/node/345?page=2

This may be due to some site or sitemap pointing to the url http://mysite.com/node/345%3Fpage%3D1?page=2. And Google indexing it.

**But** in drupal http://mysite.com/node/345%3Fpage%3D1?page=2 must show a page not found!

Any solution?

**The Question CLEARLY:**

why the url http://mysite.com/node/345%3Fpage%3D1 showing the content of http://mysite.com/node/345 instead of throwing an "not found" error?

Drupal is not considering "345%3Fpage%3D1" as the node id

Comment: First you need to enable clean URl and then Re-Index your XML sitemap and also you need to block the paginated pages in robot.txt file to avoid duplicate content problems. Please rephrase you question currently hard to understand your question.

Comment: Hi Bala, I have enabled clear URLs. The sitemap does not contain paging. I want pagination as my site is a forum. I just want the http://mysite.com/node/345%3Fpage%3D1 page to show an not found page. I thinks drupal should read "345%3Fpage%3D1" as the node id.

Comment: See the first sentence "My drupal website is indexed in Google and I found a link to http://mysite.com/node/345%3Fpage%3D1?page=2 while searching". You have not read the question carefully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I think I found a solution:

**Please correct me if I am wrong!**

Now its adding a canonical meta tag for **nodes** and for **forums** together **with the page variable**.

in my template.php I changed bartik_preprocess_node function and added bartik_preprocess_forums function.

```
function bartik_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  //start added by me
    $uri = entity_uri('node', $variables['node']);
    if($GLOBALS['pager_page_array'][0] != 0){
        $uri['options']['query']['page'] = $GLOBALS['pager_page_array'][0];
    }
    // Set the node path as the canonical URL to prevent duplicate content.
    drupal_add_html_head_link(array('rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => url($uri['path'], $uri['options'])), TRUE);
    // Set the non-aliased path as a default shortlink.
    drupal_add_html_head_link(array('rel' => 'shortlink', 'href' => url($uri['path'], array_merge($uri['options'], array('alias' => TRUE)))), TRUE);
  //end added by me

  if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'full' && node_is_page($variables['node'])) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'node-full';
  }
}

//added by me
function bartik_preprocess_forums(&$variables) {
    $uri = array();
    $uri['path'] = 'forum';
    if($variables['tid'] != 0){
        $uri['path'] = 'forum/'.$variables['tid'];
    }
    $uri['options'] = array();
    if(isset($GLOBALS['pager_page_array']) && $GLOBALS['pager_page_array'][0] != 0){
        $uri['options']['query']['page'] = $GLOBALS['pager_page_array'][0];
    }

    drupal_add_html_head_link(array('rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => url($uri['path'], $uri['options'])), TRUE);
}
```

**Also I removed the lines that adds the canonical meta tag in the node.module (But may not be a good idea to alter core modules).**

Therefor:
mysite.com/node/345%3Fpage%3D3 would have a canonical as

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/node/345">
```

and mysite.com/node/345%3Fpage%3D3?page=2 would have a canonical as

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/node/345?page=2">
```

Similarly for the forum topic pages.

Comment: This is *not* an answer to your question, which was: "why the url http://mysite.com/node/345%3Fpage%3D1 showing the content of http://mysite.com/node/345 instead of throwing an 'not found' error?"  There is not even a hint in your question that you were looking a cure for duplicated content for SEO purposes. Anyway, if that is what you wanted, you should be able to use the [Metatag](https://drupal.org/project/metatag) module to add canonical metatags.

Comment: Hey, The first sentence states that this is a problem with Google. So you should have understood that! If there is no solution, you should have suggested an alternative one like this.

Answer (score 1):

Using [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to append a query string to an URL doesn't change the address of the URL.  `%3F`, is just a slighly obscure way to write "?", and `%3D` is just a slighly obscure way to write "=".

So the URL:

```
http://mysite.com/node/345%3Fpage%3D1
```

is equivalent to this URL:

```
http://mysite.com/node/345?page=1
```

Wikipedia says:

> Reserved characters that have no reserved purpose in a particular context may also be percent-encoded but are *not semantically different* from those that are not.

So what happens is this: When that URL (`http://mysite.com/node/345%3Fpage%3D1`) is requested, page 1 of `http://mysite.com/node/345` is actually requested. If `node/345` exists on your site, Drupal will show it. If there are no pages defined, it doesn't matter, because Drupal by default ignores anything in the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) part of the URL that it does not recognise.

You wrote:

> Drupal is not considering `345%3Fpage%3D1` as the node id.

That is the correct behaviour.  The node id is "345".  What follows is what is known as a [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).  A query string starts with either `?` or `%3F`. Those two ways of starting a query string are semantically equivalent.

This is how *all* Drupal sites works, if a non-existing pagination is specified in the query-string part of the URL, it is just ignored.  Take a look of the following three URLs:

- https://drupal.org/node/2182323%3Fpage%3D42
- https://drupal.org/node/2182323?page=42
- https://drupal.org/node/2182323

Notice that they *all* go to `node/2182323` on Drupal.org.  That is because there is no page 42 for that node (there are actually no extra pages for that node).

As far as I know, there is no *simple* way to change this default behaviour to return a "Page not found" (404) response when there is no match for the query string part of the URL.

Comment: But Free Radical, mysite.com/node/345%3Fpage%3D3 is showing mysite.com/node/345

Comment: @BuntuLinux, yes - and that is Drupal's default behaviour. Do you want to change this so that Drupal returns 404 if the query string does not match a query on the site?

Comment: Yes Free Radical! That is what I want!

Comment: I just found that http://mysite.com/node/32dafsdfasdfafasdf shows the content of http://mysite.com/node/32

Comment: @BuntuLinux wrote is response to whether it was about returning a 404 status code: "That is what I want!"  However, as is evident from yiur self-aswer, this is *not* what you want.

Comment: I wanted to show 404 as I found that Google has indexed http://mysite.com/node/345%3Fpage%3D1?page=2 clearly mentioned in the question, read the question carefully! So **my solution is an alternative one** ! If you have posted a method to give a 404 for a url like this I would have accepted it as the solution.